# Data Load from CSV file to SQL DB using ADF

Tags: azure, csv, etl, azure-data-factory

I am having a.CSV file and I am trying to load to SQLDB using azure data factory but in the CSV file there is a column "Address" in that column there is comma in between address so ADF is splitting that column into multiple columns because CSV stands for (comma-separated values) and because of that address column is being split into multiple columns is there any way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you using a quote character around the fields with commas?

Comment: Hi gaurav modi, If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members.  And people are more glad to help the people when their answer could be marked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your **Dataset**, try changing the **'Column delimiter'** to another character other than ','.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According you description, It's sure that the csv file using the comma as column delimiter.

Change the dataset column delimiter to `Pipe(|)` doesn't works.

For this question, others have asked the same questions in Stack overflow. Data factory do not support change the csv file schema  during Copy Active or Data Flow.

I also asked Azure Support for helps before, the only way they suggest me is that change the source csv file.

Hope this helps.